# boto3 - better to use http calls?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3

Is it better to use `http` instead of `https` while communicating to AWS resources via `boto3` SDK if my code/app is hosted on `EC2` instance as long as the service supports it?

This is in an effort to improve performance and reduce the cost of https calls.

Comment: Is the performance of the https calls unsatisfactory?  Have you been able to measure the difference between http and https calls to determine if there is, in fact, a performance cost besides a theoretical one?

Comment: I have not measured the difference but I saw some code in the project where clients and resources were created with `use_ssl=False` and I was told it is for performance improvement. I thought I will check with experts before making the judgement call. I guess I need to do some benchmarking first before coming to the conclusion.

Comment: Generally, https wrapping/unwrapping represents a vanishingly small amount of processing overhead. You could easily get better performance overall by being thoughtful about payload caching, or even just minifying responses.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It is never better to use http when https is available.

Comment: Security models should never give in to the "hard and crunch exterior, soft and chewy interior" temptation.